# Confusion about URLMapping

Tags: grails

I'm running Grails 1.3.6.  I have this in my URLMappings.groovy file ...

```
static mappings = {
    "/$folder?/$page?"{
        controller = "Home"
        action = "index"
    }

    "/"(view:"/index")
    "500"(view:'/error')
}
```

and this is my HomeController ...

```
class HomeController {
def IOService

def index = {
    def folder = params.folder;
    def page = params.page;

    def contents = IOService.getFileContents(folder, page)  
    response.setContentType("application/json")
    response.text = contents
}   
}
```

however, when I visit my URL "/context-path/folder1/page1", I'm getting an Apache Tomcat 404 error (complaining about "/context-path/folder1").  I'm new to Grails but can't figure this out.  How can I adjust my mappings to make this work?

Thanks, - Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if controller/action definitions are case-insensitive. I've always used lowercase names. Try changing

```
controller = "Home"
```

to

```
controller = 'home'
```